# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Openshift Okd

Tags: kubernetes, xmlhttprequest, openshift, okd

So I have ajax which takes more or less 2 minutes. When I haven't configured the annotations, every 30 seconds it will produce error 504 (gateway timeout). Then I tried increasing the timeout limit to 5 minutes. Then now it can be more than 30 seconds, but every 1 minute it always produces ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, is there any other configuration to increase the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE time limit in Openshift OKD?

I hope this can be resolved because when I tried it on a local or web server like Apache there were no problems even if it took more than 1 minute[ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE IN 1 MINUTES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYJqX.png)

Comment: Have you checked access logs at every hop? You need to check the idle timeout of components that are behind the entity that logged 504 in its access log. Please include component for which you increased timeout to 5 mins.

Comment: The 2-minute request will be a problem more generally.  Any place you have some sort of proxy or gateway layer, or an HTTP request in general, you're likely to see a more-or-less 30-to-60-second timeout before the proxy or client gives up.  Can you fix the request latency issue?